# how to create rule-based diagnosis expert system

Tags: rule-engine, expert-system

our team wants to create a rule based diagnosis system.May i know what are the prerequisites for such a system?We haven't decided about programming language yet.

Comment: The prerequisites depend entirely on what your team wants to use it. So I suggest you ask them instead of us.

Comment: I mean..which tool would be more advantageous..as of now i read some snippets about DROOLS,Pyke,CLIPS etc...but I am confused which one we should be using...can someone help in giving the pros and cons of these rule engines? sorry for not being clear in the previous ques..